# Aftership API in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have been trying to insert Aftership (Courier tracking website) API in my Google scripts. The following script is to create a new tracking. I am very close, the only thing I'm not able to figure out is where to put the parameter `tracking_number`. The API documentation for this request is [here](https://docs.aftership.com/api/4/trackings/post-trackings). Example tracking number: EI790662622IN of India Post Domestic.

```
function myFunction() {

    var apikey = "GENERATEDAPIKEY";

    var options = {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "headers" : {
        "aftership-api-key": apikey,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    };

    var aftership_url = "https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(aftership_url, options);

    var result = response.getContentText();

    Logger.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you should insert your [payload (look at advanced parameters)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

```
function aftership() {
  var apikey = "your api key";

  var payload = { "tracking": { "tracking_number": "EI790662622IN" } };

  var options = {
    "method"  : "POST",
    "contentType": 'application/json',
    "headers" : {
      "aftership-api-key": apikey,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  var aftership_url = "https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(aftership_url, options);
  var result = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

**but** To have it working you have to enable the courier in [Courier Api settings](https://secure.aftership.com/settings/courier)

Your code missed:

- contentType in options
- payload formatted as JSON string, with scheme as requested by the api.

Comment: Thanks, but it is still giving error - Request failed for https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"meta":{"code":4006,"message":"`tracking` object is required.","type":"BadRequest"},"data":{"tracking_number":"EI790662622IN"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response). (line 20, file "Aftership")

Comment: fixed and tested :) not it works, but you have to enable the courier in security settings

Comment: The second edit is giving me error "Missing } after property list" in the "payload": JSON.stringify(payload); line. Yes, the courier is added in the settings.

Comment: Check what you copied, I cannot get the same error with that code... :/

Comment: I tried full copy pasting, still facing that error.

Comment: There is an exceeding ; after JSON.strigify. please remove it

Comment: Yeah!! It is working now, thanks. Can you tell me where did you get the payload formatting scheme? I cannot find it.

Comment: In the first link of the answer. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "scheme as requested by the api".

Comment: From the link that you posted in your question. There is an example  of a complete payload (section Body)